# document.getElementById.innerText shifts position of controls to right

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have table which contains AsynFileUpload control, I have written javascript where it checks for file extension which is to be uploaded and after check, I am using document.getElementById.innerText to set text for label.
When text is set to the label there is shift in position of all controls or table(every shifts to right).

I don't know why this is happening please help.

Code:

```
function uploadStarted() {
       if (document.getElementById("<%=ddlArtifactType.ClientID%>").value == "Video") {
      var fileExtension = document.getElementById("<%=videoFile.ClientID%>").firstChild.value;
      var extension = fileExtension.substr(fileExtension.lastIndexOf("."), fileExtension.length-           fileExtension.lastIndexOf("."));
       if (extension.toString() != ".mp4" && extension.toString() != ".MP4") {
         document.getElementById("<%=lblError.ClientID%>").innerText = "File not supported";
         return false;
      }
```

Comment: can you paste the code?

Comment: its not formatted how to paste is line by line?